# Kiosk External Link Trapping C#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, hyperlink, blazor, kiosk

I am currently developing a kiosk app. I unfortunately have hyperlinks embedded in an element on the page. These links are very small and decorated to be hidden but need to be there. Is there any way using C# i can trap the redirection. So when the link is clicked by someone either purposely or accidental it will prevent navigation. Only if the kiosk opens another tab its technically "Out Of Order".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent the default action of the link for the click event by applying  the @oneventname:preventDefault directive attribute, as for example:

```
<a href="/counter" @onclick:preventDefault >Go to counter</a>
```

This setting will prevent the navigation from other locations to the Counter component. You may also use it with the @onclick directive, if you wish to define 
a handler for the click event, as for example:

```
<a href="/counter" @onclick="ClickHandler" @onclick:preventDefault >Go to 
  counter</a>
```

> Only if the kiosk opens another tab its technically "Out Of Order".

Not sure what you're trying to say here...